# Physical dimensions of the Planet Express building

Tags: futurama, architecture

Does someone know (or can calculate precisely enough by his eyes) Planet Express building's dimensions and schema of inner rooms?

All I have found so far is [this image](http://pool.theinfosphere.org/images/f/ff/Planet_Express_Floorplan_%28game%29.svg), but it is from a game so I am not sure how accurate it is according to the series.

This one looks different and more real:
[image: The Planet Express Floorplan]

Pictures are Courtesy of [The Infosphere (Futurama Wiki)](http://theinfosphere.org/Main_Page)

Comment: Corrections of grammar and logic are good, but please, do not change my words and structure of my sentences. Thanks.

Comment: why?  The edits bitmask made did nothing to change the meaning or intent of the question.

Comment: I just do not like such rephrasing, no offence. For example, I would not say "more detailed cross secion, but it's still not precise enough.". Anyhow, it would be nice to get an answer.

Comment: This _is_ a collaboratively edited site. Sometimes, the phrasing of your post _will_ be edited in order to clarify the meaning or intent of your question. Others, being used to this site being edited in this manner, will not always expect the question to be in exact words you would produce yourself. Remember that your question is here to be useful to others, and not _just you_, so others will act in the interests of improving the question to facilitate it actually getting good answers for the benefit of themselves and others.

Comment: That said, as the asker of your question, it _is_ acceptable for you to object to edits that change your question in ways you're uncomfortable with, and I think it was fair to revert that particular edit. However I suggest you get used to the idea that people are going to edit your posts and change your phrasing here, or you're just going to experience a lot of friction with the community. This question itself is primarily going to be improved _by changing the way it's written_ in small ways - not just through spelling or grammar corrections. The edit you rolled back did more than that though.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs the only thing i don't like about Bitmask's edit was the funky grammar of his opening line, and the use of "film" rather than "series".  Otherwise, superior to the original question as far as readability, and did not change what was being asked at all.

Comment: This is a collaboratively edited site, I understand this idea and I like it. I know the rules and I really appreciate corrections of grammar or improving my question by clarifying something, or fixing my errors in any way, or improving formatting. But indeed there was "more than that though", and this is why I rolled PART of the changes back.

Comment: And, by the way, the second image is NOT the "**more detailed**", it is "**different**". Structure of rooms is different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Planet Express buiding's layout changes from episode to episode, much like th "magic door" beneath the stairwell in *The Simpsons*, which sometimes leads to a closet and other times leads to the basement. If one listens to the commentaries for many *Futurama* episodes the creators of the show actually make fun of this phenomenon, which also occurs in Bender's chest compartment - which Matt Groening refers to as being like Felix's bag, as it contains whatever Bender needs it to contain for the story to progress - and in the Planet Express ship itself.

Since the layout of the building, aside from the main central room, changes in every episode, there is no set floor-plan possible, let alone available for viewing. They made the one above up for the purposes of the game, but it has been contradicted by many episodes of the series. Note the complete lack of the newly-revealed "Chart Room" in either of those maps.

An in-universe explanation of this could be similar to an episode of *Star Trek: Enterprise*, the name of which escapes me, where the crew discover a time-travelling spacecraft that is larger on the inside than it is on the outside. I believe the solution they devise (while admitting that, since this vessel is from the future, they don't actually understand if their idea is correct) is that the extra space is in an artificial dimension. Farnsworth may have done something similar in his home.

Comment: The Enterprise episode in question is 2x16, [Future Tense](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Future_Tense_(episode))

Comment: Thanks for that. I have *Futurama* on DVD, but not *Enterprise*.